# How do I parse multiple values

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program for class that calculates the discriminant of a given equation when the user inputs coefficients. I am having trouble converting an input from string to int though. My teacher has his heart set on making sure I have the user input the coefficients all in one line which is where the trouble comes in.

Here is my code so far:

```
/*
 * Write a program that will determine the number and type of roots 
 * for a quadratic equation, given the coefficients a, b, and c.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the coefficients for a quadratic equation");
        String roots = input.nextLine();
        int a=Integer.parseInt(roots);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(roots);
        int c=Integer.parseInt(roots);
        System.out.println(a);
        int discriminant = (int)Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);  

        if(discriminant > 0)
        {
          System.out.println(a + "^2" + b + "x" + c + "has 2 real roots");
        }
        else if(discriminant == 0)
        {
          System.out.println(a + "^2" + b + "x" + c + "has 1 real root");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println(a + "^2" + b + "x" + c + "has two imaginary roots");
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code  is functional but whenever the user includes a space between the coefficients they enter (as my teacher wants) Java spits out this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 2 3"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
exit status 1
```

How do I properly parse through data? My teacher recommended using substrings but I am not quite sure about that as when the users inputs values greater than 10 the program will have trouble figuring out when the value entered starts and ends. I am a bit stuck with this so any  help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could `split` that `root` string on `" "` to obtain an array of three values which you can then parse. Ore use `nextInt` three times instead of `nextLine`

Comment: Or if your teacher is dead set on you using substring, you can use `indexOf` to find the first space in the string, substring till there, then use `indexOf again on the remaining substring and substring again

Comment: Just because nobody has actually put it here in a comment yet, you are getting an error because `Integer#parseInt()` tries to parse the whole string as one integer, so the string you give it should be entirely number characters.  When it sees a space in the string, it no longer knows how to turn it into a number.

Comment: Or this whole mess can be avoided by using `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`.

Comment: Yeah I feel a bit silly for asking this but now I understand it completely which is much better than whatever my teacher wanted me to understand. Thank you for bearing with my stupid question  :)

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I convinced him to not have me use substrings. It seems a bit silly that he would do that considering how easy it is to do without it but that's  what he had students do for years apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `.split()` method like so:

```
String[] roots = input.nextLine().split();
int a=Integer.parseInt(roots[0]);
int b=Integer.parseInt(roots[1]);
int c=Integer.parseInt(roots[2]);
```

The `.split()` method can split a String into multiple parts. By default, it splits spaces, so "1 2 3" would become "1", "2" and "3". We can then parse them using `Integer.parseInt()`, with `roots[0], roots[1], roots[2]` being the position in the array for `1`, `2` and `3` respectively.

Or you can use `.nextInt()` like so:

```
int a=input.nextInt();
int b=input.nextInt();
int c=input.nextInt();
```

You are getting the error because you are tring to parse a number with spaces (which is not a number). Either strip out the spaces or split them into multiple numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up doing this. Something clicked in my brain when I read this and I understand the concept much better now. I actually feel a bit stupid  for asking this in the first place which is  good I suppose.

Comment: @LinusZwaka All's good! Well all learn some way, don't we? Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Popular methods you can use include the trim() String method Java has which will eliminate leading and trailing white space. As well as a the Split() String method which by default will split the string into an array of values split by white space. If you need to split by any other value you can send in a string parameter into the split() method for example str.split(",") will split the string by comma separated values

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(" ")) {
        String[] values = line.split(" ");
        if (values.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter 3 entry only");
        } else {
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter valid number");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter: 1 2 3");
    }
    if ("exit".equals(line) || "quit".equals(line))
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually will use this for my next assignment where I need to have to parse through many values.